# My Dell Inspiron 15-3567 no longer recognizes HDMI output

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

As of today, it seems my HDMI output is not working to connect to my second monitor.

xrandr --prop

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0009e5c20600000000
        011a0104952213780a24109759548e27
        1e505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101641b5677500013303020
        360058c21000001aa21756b950002d30
        3020360058c21000001a000000fe0048
        584e4e4a804e54313554303000000000
        00004101940110000009010a20200002
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1366x768      60.00*+  47.98  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

➜  ~ ls /sys/class/drm
card0  card0-eDP-1  renderD128  version

➜  ~ inxi -SMCGx

```
System:    Host: anthony-ubuntu Kernel: 4.15.0-48-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu3)
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Dell product: Inspiron 15-3567 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Dell model: 04YVDP v: A00 serial: N/A
           UEFI: Dell v: 2.5.1 date: 05/31/2018
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-7200U (-MT-MCP-) 
           arch: Kaby Lake rev.9 cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10848
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 790 MHz 2: 778 MHz 3: 738 MHz
           4: 745 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 620 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: i915
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.8 Direct Render: Yes
```

I tried the following: update system using ' sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade '

tried sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 --auto ; but since it doesn't even see an HDMI output, didn't work.

Thoughts and advise please? :D

Comment: forgot to add - I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic)

Comment: Make sure that the HDMI port is enabled in your BIOS. Report back.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply!

I ran ' sudo dmidecode | less'

and did not find anything pertaining to HDMI. but when I re ran the 'xrandr' without the monitor plugged in I got 

HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: You probably have to actually enter the BIOS to check for the HDMI port being seen/enabled. Otherwise, you may have a function key (like maybe F4) that enables/disables the port/monitor.